# Boolean Operations On polygons

Tags: javascript, clipping

I currently implementing graphing software, that can graph inequalities (or system of inequalities) like f(x,y)

I found approximating polygons for isoline f(x,y)=g(x,y), but now I'm facing the problem for finding polygon,that approximates region.

I found excellent Javascript Library http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/ for doing this, however I can't get how to use it properly.

For example, how to use it if I want to find XOR of two polygons, that represent circles of radii 1 and 2 (one polygon lies inside another, so I want to find region outside one circle and inside another).

Answer (score 1):

> For example, how to use it if I want to find XOR of two polygons, that represent circles of radii 1 and 2 (one polygon lies inside another, so I want to find region outside one circle and inside another

Firstly, JSClipper (a Java translation of [Clipper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/polyclipping)) only accepts polygons as flattened paths with integer coordinates. Therefore you'll need to scale up your circle radii by a suitable factor (depending on desired precision) and generate flattened paths using a [PointsOnEllipse](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordcirclealgorithm.html) algorithm.

Then, given that one circle lies inside the other, and this inner circle represents a 'hole' to the outer circular polygon, then its orientation will need to be the reverse of the outer polygon (as explained [here](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper/documentation/Docs/Units/ClipperLib/Types/PolyFillType.htm)).

Solutions to JSClipper's boolean operations will remain as flattened paths, though the solution to an XOR operation on the paths you've specified will be these exact same paths (ie unchanged) since the two paths will still represent the outer and inner contours of the returned polygon region.

Once any boolean operations are completed, you need to reverse any initial polygon scaling to derive floating point coordinates representing your flattened paths.

Finally, there's no simple way to reconstruct circular/elliptical radii and origins etc from flattened paths.